# Rails scope with belongs_to and has_one through relationship

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, model, scope

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :availabilities
  has_many :time_slots, through: :availabilities    
end

class TimeSlot < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :availability
  has_one :employee, through: :availability
end

class Availability < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee
  has_many :time_slots 
end
```

How can I create a scope for only the time slots that have an availability that has a specific employee? If, an employee id is passed into the scope.

```
class TimeSlot < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :availability
  has_one :employee, through: :availability

    scope :employee, -> (employee_id) { joins(:availability).where("availabilities.employee_id=?", employee_id) if employee_id.present? }
end
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: when I call something like TimeSlot.for_employee(1) it is not returning the TimeSlots

Comment: check the generated SQL and see if it is what you need

Comment: Just updated the scope and got this error. ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "availabilities"

Comment: @AndreyDeineko thank you, i have added the correct scope.

Comment: so you got it working, right?

Comment: Yes thank you for you help!